# Use RXJS and AsyncPipe instead of Observable.subscribe

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, angularfire2

In my firebase (angularfire2) app I want return document for each element of collection. For this I use Observables + .subscribe(). But I want to get alternative using RXJS and AsyncPipe.

I tried to use next RXJS chains:

```
this.shortlisted$ = this.db.collection(`interestingStartups`).valueChanges().pipe(mergeMap(actions => actions.map(el => {
 return this.db.doc(`startups/${(<any>el).startupUid}`).valueChanges().pipe(mergeMap(el => of([el])));
})));
```

And use `*ngFor="let s of shortlisted$ | async"` inside HTML template. But it not works. Angular shows next error "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays"

My current code (Observables + .subscribe) which works:

```
this.db.collection('interestingStartups').valueChanges().subscribe((el:any) => {
 el.forEach(is => {
  this.db.doc('startups/' + is.startupUid).get().subscribe(s => {
   this.shortlisted.push(s.data());
  })
 })        
});
```

And I just use pure `*ngFor` without AsyncPipe, i.e. `*ngFor="let s of shortlisted"`

I want assign result into `this.shortlisted` using RXJS operators like `mergeMap` or similar. At the current moment I was not able to find working solution for this

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should work.

```
this.shortlisted$ = this.db.collection('interestingStartups').valueChanges().pipe(
  switchMap(el => combineLatest(
    el.map(is => this.db.doc('startups/' + is.startupUid).get())
  ))
);
```

It starts by getting the list of interestign startups, then for each startup, it gets the document for the startup, and it uses `combineLatest` to concatenate them.

Comment: Note that you also can use `combineLatest` as an operator (which then removes the `switchMap`), but you will get the list of interesting startups as your first item of the array

Comment: Hm... I just changed `.get()` with `.valueChanges()` and it started to work. Your answer is big step forward for me because I spent so many time trying to use different RXJS options. Thanks a lot! And I will need to read about `combineLatest`...

Comment: `combineLatest` does what it says, it combines the latest values of each observable given to it. It's like `forkJoin`, except that `forkJoin` combines the last values of closed observables (such as http calls)